# readyRead() signal in qextserialport is not being emitted

Tags: c++, serial-port, signals-slots, qextserialport, qiodevice

I am using [qextserialport](https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) to communicate with a Bluetooth device on a Windows 8.1. I defined a **ComPort** class. I need to first write a message `{0xA9,0x55}` on "COM5" to ask the Bluetooth device start transmitting data. Then I can start reading data. I have a terminal application that shows I have written the message and data are available on "COM5".

**Problem definition:**

In *comport.cpp*, neither `waitForBytesWritten()` nor `waitForReadyRead()` return `true`. Number of available bytes is zero and the `onReadyRead()` slot is not invoked. What's wrong in my code?

**comport.h**

```
#ifndef COMPORT_H
#define COMPORT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qextserialport.h"
#include "qextserialenumerator.h"

class QTimer;

class ComPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ComPort(const QString &portName);
    ~ComPort();

private:
    QextSerialPort* port;

    void     setupPort();


private slots:
    void onReadyRead();
};

#endif // COMPORT_H
```

and **comport.cpp**

```
#include "comport.h"
ComPort::ComPort(const QString &portName)
{
    QString strPort;
    this->port = new QextSerialPort(portName);
    this->setupPort();

    connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));

    if (port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) == true)
    {
        const char mydata[] = {static_cast<char>(0xA9),static_cast<char>(0x55)};
        QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(mydata, sizeof(mydata));
        port->write(data);
        if(port->waitForBytesWritten(100))
            qDebug() << "Wrote the message";

        QByteArray responseData = port->readAll();
        while (port->waitForReadyRead(2000))
               responseData += port->readAll();

        qDebug() << "Num of bytes: " << port->bytesAvailable();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Device is not turned on";
    }
}

ComPort::~ComPort()
{
    delete port;
}

void ComPort::setupPort()
{
    port->setBaudRate(BAUD115200);
    port->setTimeout(100); // Does nothing in Eventdriven mode!
    port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    port->setStopBits(STOP_1);
    port->setQueryMode(QextSerialPort::EventDriven);
}

void ComPort::onReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray bytes;
    int a = port->bytesAvailable();
    bytes.resize(a);
    port->read(bytes.data(), bytes.size());
    qDebug() << "bytes read:" << bytes.size();
    qDebug() << "bytes:" << bytes;
}
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what FLOW_OFF might be.  But "off" is rarely correct, QSerialPort::HardwareControl should be your first choice.

Comment: @Hans Passant Yet, with the current setting, I see on the terminal application that I receive the data from the device. I used `HardwareControl`, but no change.

Comment: Why don't you want to use standard Qt 5 class QSerialPort ?